# Clicking any checkbox only activates one field?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a form where each individual checkbox has a number input field attached to it which will only show when the checkbox is checked. So far I've got this:

```
  <!-- Option1 -->
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" onchange="showqt()" value="Button Chicken Amritsari" id="c1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
                              Button Chicken Amritsari<i><br>(Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4 " id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
                            <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
                            <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                              <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- Option 1 ends -->
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" onchange="showqt()" value="Chicken Korma Awadhi" id="c2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="c2">
                              Chicken Korma Awadhi<br><i> (Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
                            <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
                            <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
                              <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                              <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
                              <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

And here's my JS:

```
function showqt(){
  if ($('.showman').is(":checked")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('className')
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'inline';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Now, as long as I have only one checkbox it works fine. However, when I add more checkboxes, regardless of which checkbox I click only the input field for the first checkbox shows up. I want the input field for each individual checkbox to show up depending on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Is there a global way of doing this or do I need to write custom JS for each checkbox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide text box based on check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766306/show-hide-text-box-based-on-check-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <!-- Option1 -->
                          <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" onchange="showqt(this)" value="Button Chicken Amritsari" id="c1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
                                  Button Chicken Amritsari<i><br>(Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-md-4 " id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
                                <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
                                <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
                                  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                                  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
                                  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Option 1 ends -->
                          <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" onchange="showqt(this)" value="Chicken Korma Awadhi" id="c2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="c2">
                                  Chicken Korma Awadhi<br><i> (Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
                                <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
                                <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
                                  <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                                  <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
                                  <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>

function showqt(obj){
    if ($(obj).is(":checked")) {
      
      jQuery(obj).parents(".form-row").find("#ifYes").show();
    }
    else {
        jQuery(obj).parents(".form-row").find("#ifYes").hide();
    }
  }
```

It will works.

Comment: It's not global. If I use `data-target` I'll have to set individual IDs for each field

Comment: I changed the global. you should change the function showqt(this) in html.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the jQuery approach:

```
$('#ifYes').css('display','block'); and $('#ifYes').css('display','none');
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using only CSS using the `:checked` pseudo-selector. The snippet below uses the `~` general sibling combinator to toggle visibility of the counter.

```css
.form-row {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.counter {
  display: none;
 }
.showman:checked ~ .counter{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Option1 -->
<div class="form-row">

    <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" value="Button Chicken Amritsari" id="c1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
      Button Chicken Amritsari<i><br>(Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
    </label>
    
  <div class="counter">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
    <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Option 1 ends -->

<div class="form-row">

    <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" value="Chicken Korma Awadhi" id="c2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="c2">
      Chicken Korma Awadhi<br><i> (Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
    </label>

  <div class="counter">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
    <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can run the snippet to see the example. In this example both the checkbox and the counter must be siblings of each other.

Comment: I tried it in my code. Ended up messing my formatting and didn't work either

Comment: It also breaks my buttons.

Comment: As I said, to use this specific example you would need to refactor your code so that the two elements are siblings. More importantly it illustrates a very lightweight strategy that could be used to provide the functionality you are describing. If a little CSS breaks your buttons there is probably a deeper problem that it is exposing.

Comment: By siblings, I assume you mean inside the same div? That's gonna be a problem as I'm using the bootstrap grid to align everything